# Editing custom options for a custom layout template

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, custom, product-view

Hopefully someone can help or offer some advice. I want to change the layout of one product page. I have created the custom `view.phtml` and within design of the product inserted the new template, all fine.

Now I need to **change the layout of the custom options**, but only for this page, not across all products. I also may need to add custom classes for styling etc etc.

I have noticed the `container1` `container2` and how they are linked to the `wrapper` and `wrapper.bottom` in the `catalog.xml` but if I change anything here all products will be changed.

Is there anyway to **pull in the custom options for that simple product** just for my custom `view.phtml` template without using container 1 and 2. Maybe reference a new container? As I said i don't want all products being affected by the change.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say "..layout of one product page..." you mean that only one specific product identified by sku,attrbute_set or whatsover need to have a different layout ?

Comment: Yeah just that one product, within that one product i have included a custom layout template, and its that template where i need to modify the options for that product. I essentially want to use bootstrap and add some effects and adjust how the select boxes appear but only for that one product, all other simple products on the site can stay the same as they.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new theme only for that product.

```
app/design/frontend/your_theme  
app/design/frontend/your_theme_for_one_product/layout
app/design/frontend/your_theme for_one_product/template/catalog/product
```

put your modified catalog.xml in the new folder layout,
and your view.phtml in your new catalog/product folder

If you need also mods on css and you have to replicate the folder structure above in the skin folder

```
skin/frontend/your_theme/...  
skin/frontend/your_theme_for_one_product/...
```

Then open Magento Admin and edit you product.

In the "Design" section open the "Custom design" list and choose your_theme for_one_product

Save the product, test in the frontend
and let us know.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, thanks, I have done that, and the custom template shows up fine. What I'm trying to do is edit the custom options that pull through on that custom template, to change css for input boxes for just that page i would need to set up classes and id's. I understand it would be found in select.phtml but changing that would change all products on the website.

Comment: Just copy the select.phtml into the new theme folder template/catalog/...  for the css I edit the answer.

Comment: I get you now, my mistake was to reference a new customview.phtml within the same theme instead of creating a new theme folder and doing it that way. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: glad to ear that, if mine is the proper answer please accept it. thank you ;)